# Image upload in React Native (Expo), using fetch results in 400 error

Tags: react-native, expo, multipartform-data, fetch-api

I have been struggling with image upload for days.
I’m using formdata like this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', {
  uri: uri,
  name: `name`,
  type: `image/jpeg`,
});
```

uri on iOS is something like `asset-library://asset/path` on Android it is like `content://media/external/images/media/25377`.

```
let options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
  },
};
let response = await fetch("https://myserverurl", options)
```

I tried every trick reading the image as blob, removing content-type, other libraries like axios, etc…
No matter what I always get back a 400 bad file format error.

Is there something I’m missing with formdata?
(On the backend we use ASP.NET)

Comment: You need (at least for android) full path of file not just android file system db path.

Comment: I'm moving the image after it is taken to the camera roll with: `MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(this.state.photo.uri)` and after that I get back these asset and content urls, not the full path urls.

Answer (score 6):

We have had a similar issue and were able to solve the issue the following way. 
We are using a NodeJS backend (with multer) to handle the file uploads.

**Expo - Mobile App Code**

```
  // extract the filetype
  let fileType = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

  let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("photo", {
    uri,
    name: `photo.${fileType}`,
    type: `image/${fileType}`
  });

  let options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  };
```

We are executing the request with `fetch(apiUrl, options)`.

The `uri` is the local file path (full URI e.g., `file:///...`) of the photo in our case and `apiUrl` is the endpoint of the server-side.

I think the issue might be with the type and format of `uri` in formdata. Have you tried to use the `uri` returned by the image picker?

Comment: I have yet to try uploading straight from image picker. But in my use case I no longer have `file:///` uri. After the image is taken with a custom camera app, it is moved to the camera roll. And after that, it only has an `asset-library://` uri (in case of iOS) and a `content://` uri in case of Android. I have no idea how to get the absolute uri after moving it to the camera roll.

Comment: Do you ask for the correct permissions (e.g., CAMERA_ROLL and STORAGE) before you try to access the image? Alternatively, I would try to pass the orignal URI of the image picker using the navigation props to the function/class that is doing the upload.

Comment: Yes, I do, otherwise I would not have access to the uri. Btw I tried uploading using the picker with original uri. Still failed, but with a different error. Now it is 500 internal server error

Comment: We have a NodeJS backend so it's hard for me to help you with ASP.NET. But we had an issue on the server side with the URI format at first. Maybe that's something to check. Can you post your server-side code that receives the file? Sorry, that I cannot help you more.

Comment: We ended up using a different option. Alternative: encode the image as a base64 string, send the string to the server, convert the string back to the image format. This worked a lot smoother than the initial approach with the file upload.

Comment: After 3 hours, your solution fixed it for me. I did not add the "type" to it. After adding the file type, it worked on Android (> 8, issue started with 9+). GOSH. Thanks!