# Expo React Native upload an image to Laravel in backend

Tags: laravel, react-native, expo

I am fairly new to coding and I'm in the learning phase for both React Native and Laravel. I was working on some practice project and I needed to upload an image from my React Native app to the Laravel server and from the server I could save it on a cloud or something. I can upload and display the image on the app using expo-image-picker but I just can't seem to get it to post it to the server using formData.

Also, why is that when I console.log formData why is it showing an empty object?

My code to loading the image and uploading it:

```
pickImage = async () => {
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [4, 3],
  quality: 1,
});

console.log(result);
if(!result.cancelled)
{
  this.setState({
    image : result.uri
  })
}



// ImagePicker saves the taken photo to disk and returns a local URI to it
  let localUri = result.uri;
  //console.log("localUri:", localUri)
  let filename = localUri.split('/').pop();
  console.log("filename:", filename)

  // extract the filetype
  //let fileType = localUri.substring(localUri.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
  //console.log(fileType)
  let fileType = localUri.substring(localUri.lastIndexOf(":") + 1,localUri.lastIndexOf(";")).split("/").pop();
  console.log("type:", fileType)

  let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("photo", {
    uri : localUri,
    name: `photo.${fileType}`,
    type: `image/${fileType}`
  });

  console.log("formdata", formData)

  let options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  };

  let response = await fetch(`${this.props.url}imagetest`, options)
  result = await response.json()
  console.log(result)
```

My simple code for api.php in Laravel is:

```
Route::post("/imagetest", function (Request $request) {


return ["uploaded" => $request->hasFile("photo")];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution at

[send image using Expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845956/image-upload-in-react-native-expo-using-fetch-results-in-400-error)

The problem I was having, I was testing it by running the code on web, when I ran it on the device I could see the formdata as well as the image was been uploaded too